# Запрос MySQL на выборку записей по столетию

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, содержащая информацию про космические объекты, в частности, их тип (например, звезда, планета и т.д.) и дату их открытия (тип DATETIME). Необходимо написать запрос, который выводил бы количество объектов каждого типа, которые были открыты в каждом столетии. Вывод должен выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `GROUP BY object_type` + `PIVOT` вручную на `CASE YEAR(discovery_date) MOD 100`.

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) count,
  type_id,
  FLOOR(YEAR(found_at) / 100) centry 
FROM test
GROUP BY type_id, FLOOR(YEAR(found_at) / 100);
```

И выложил вариант решения здесь, чтобы было видно в действии: 
[Увидеть можно тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22dd2b/4/0)

Comment: *продублируйте* текст запроса в самом ответе, ответ должен быть полноценным а не ссылкой на сторонний ресурс

Comment: Продублируйте лучше в ответе, а то может потеряться

Comment: Автор чётко указывает: *Вывод должен выглядеть следующим образом*. В данном ответе вывод выглядит иначе.